# Convert DataTable to Entity Objects and add to Table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am quite new to Programming/MVC, so apologies for any incorrect terminology.

In my MVC application using Entity Framework, I am struggling to create some functionality that allows a user to upload a CSV file, parse it, and add it to my database (generated by code first).

I have a Project Model, and I want a user to be able to upload a CSV file of Deliverables for specific Projects. I will then have a View that displays Project Details, and a full list of all Deliverables as well.

Following a pretty straight forward tutorial, I have the CSV parser in my view which presents the DataTable after parsing. The View renders fine, and the this is the controller I am using:

```
public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase upload)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
            {

                if (upload.FileName.EndsWith(".CSV"))
                {
                    Stream stream = upload.InputStream;
                    DataTable csvTable = new DataTable();
                    using (CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(stream), true))
                    {
                        csvTable.Load(csvReader);
                    }
                    return View(csvTable);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("File", "This file format is not supported");
                    return View();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("File", "Please Upload Your file");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Tutorial: http://techbrij.com/read-csv-asp-net-mvc-file-upload

I now can't for the life of me understand how I can now put this Datatable into my Deliverables table, whilst referencing the specific Project the Deliverables are for. For example, how can the code know that the deliverables in the CSV file are for Project#123 and not Project#122...

I am hoping for nudge in the right direction, and really appreciate any assistance.

Comment: *how I can now put this Datatable into my Deliverables table* - Are you looking to combine two data tables on the back-end?  Or are you looking to display specific contents of the uploaded CSV on the front-end?

Comment: So, I am trying to upload the CSV data, and store it in my Deliverables table. I will then add to my Project Details View the details of a specific Project, and another table on that view that displays specific contents from the Deliverables table (which I understand how to do). So I also need my File Upload to reference the Project ID field so the program knows to store the CSV data against the correct Project (Which I am not sure how to do). Hope that makes sense.

Comment: So are you looking to parse the CSV file on the server-side to extract the "project ID" from the CSV?

Comment: Yes I need the server side to parse the CSV file and add  the contents of the CSV file into the Deliverables table.